# How to solve this Ratio problem

Tags: rational-numbers

I am preparing for an olympiad and came across the following question in a workbook. There is answer but no explanation:

> The ratio between the number of passengers travelling by Ist and IInd class between two railway stations is 1:50, whereas the ratio of Ist and IInd class fares between the same stations is 3:1.If on a particular day, Rs. 1325 is collected from the passengers travelling between these stations by these classes, then what was the amount collected from the IInd class passengers?
> (A)Rs.750   (B)Rs.850   (C)Rs.1000    (D)Rs.1250
>
>
> Answer:(D)

I want to know the explanation to the answer.

**Note:Rs. stands for INR(Indian Rupee) which is the currency of India**

Comment: Sorry for the tag, I saw no other suitable tag for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think D is the correct answer. Suppose in a day $x$ number of passengers travel by 1st class, then $50x$ number of passengers will travel by 2nd class. Now if each passenger in 1st class pays Rs. $3y$, then each of 2nd class will pay Rs. $y$. Now by hypothesis, $3xy+50xy=1325$. Thus $50xy=1250$.

Comment: Sorry I typed B instead of D, but the ratio of passengers is 1:50, So if x passengers travel by Ist class , 50x will travel in IInd class.

Comment: yes...sorry I typed wrongly...now corrected

Comment: Is it alright now?

Comment: Yes ok now cleared